# Rails 3.1, FactoryGirl or Factory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, factory, factory-bot

I am trying to build tests using specs, and I am confused about using FactoryGirl or Factory,
I have FactoryGirl 2.3.2 installed, as I have `gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 1.2"` in GemFile

The declaration of Factory is at /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/factory_girl-2.3.2/lib/factory_girl/deprecated.rb

I see Factory used in examples like this: [How do I create an association with a has_many :through relationship in Factory Girl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584715/how-do-i-create-an-association-with-a-has-many-through-relationship-in-factory)

Any idea please ? is it Ok to use Factory at Rails 3.1 ? not always ? not at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can understand of deprecation.rb, only methods defined by FactoryGirl (e.g. aliases) are deprecated when using with Factory. I guess you can keep on using Factory.xxxx calls to build/create instances.